# JasperReports Server: Limit visibility of scheduled jobs to the creator

Tags: jasperserver

We have a bunch of reports in our server that are shared among many users. The reports implement data filtering based on user attributes so the same report will show different data to different users. Each user gets a login to our server and the ROLE_USES gives them read-only access to the shared reports.

Our problem is that users can see, edit and even delete each other's scheduled jobs. According to the documentation "Typical users only see the jobs that they have defined themselves; administrators see the jobs defined by all users.". But that doesn't seem to be the case.

One of the workaround seemed to be to create separate roles for the users and then make copies of the reports. We have tried that. Two users, each having access to different sets of reports. When they go to the "View" -> ""Schedules" menu, they still see all scheduled job, even the ones that are for the reports that they have no access to!

I would really appreciate is someone had any clue where to look. We've been searching through many JasperReports configuration files but can't find any clues...

We are using Community Edition 6.2.1 of JasperReports Server.

Answer (score 0):

**Analysis**

Usually you want to separate the users into different groups. Those groups can be used to assign rights. So lets assume you've got two different groups, *Finance* and *Operations*. The following rules should get created:

- `RULE_FINANCE`
- `RULE_OPERATIONS`

Regarding the setup for the users, just assign the new roles to the users.

*NOTE: Keep in mind that `ROLE_USER` always needs to be assigned to a user for it to function correctly. **Do not remove this role from users**. Where applicable, you can remove rights on e.g. folder for this user, though.*

**Using the roles**

Now every role or group should be able to see only the reports, folders or schedules the role or group has created.

The *jasperadmin*, which is the highest level admin of the *Community Edition*, is always able to see all schedules, reports and folder for all users and could deactivate the schedules in any case.

Comment: Thanks.

As I mentioned in my post, "One of the workaround....",  we have created multiple roles and make the copies of the reports. In this setup, users would look like this:
User1: ROLE_USER | ROLE_A
User: ROLE_USER | ROLE_B

We would then create a copy of the reports in two folders:
Folder A - visble to ROLE_A
Folder B - visible to ROLE_B

Now each user only sees their reports. However, user A still sees the schedules of user B (in the View -> Schedules page) and can edit/delete them.

Comment: This is really strange, since the default behaviour wouldn't allow different roles to access the schedules of another role, e.g. [see here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/907016/how-make-all-scheduled-jobs-visible-all-users-not-just-administrators). Maybe this is because of the copy. Try letting both roles access one report and don't provide a copy.